# How to make the form dynamic

Tags: php, html

Lets say inside my sql have some data:

name | table_no 
Apple | c1 
Grape | c1

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){ //read the data inside sql and display out

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "Name: ". $row['name']. "<br>". "Table No.: ". $row['table_no']. "<br>";
    }


}else{ // insert the data if inside sql have no data of table_no

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

        $value = $_POST['value'];
        $table = $_POST['table'];

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO testing (name, table_no) VALUES ('$value', '$table')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}

?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <h2>C1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" value="c1" name="table">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit">

</form>

<form method="post" action="">
    <h2>C2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" value="c2" name="table">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

My problem is, how to make the webpage more dynamic that can automatically  change to a blank form that can be fill in the data(table_no) and if the form already has the data it will display the data instead of showing the blank form to let user fill in.

Comment: Use JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: @chade_ can you show me how can be done or is there any sample code out there i can reference for. I tried to search yesterday but doesn't find any sample code or tutorial that relate my question..

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically update the value in your input. Assuming $result is the result of your SQL query and there is a field named C1 in $result, here an example for your form C1:

```
<!-- langage: html -->
<form method="post" action="">
    <h2>C1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result['c1']; ?>" name="table">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: if i have multiple form (C1, C2, C3,...) I just change the value inside the $result?

Comment: For a better answer, I need to know the structure containing the data from your table. In my example, I assumed that `$result` is an array containing several fields ('c1,'c2,'c3' ...). Then yes in each form, you change the $result : $result['c2] for the input C2